# Laravel - How to clear config:cache on each request

Tags: laravel

I am working on a project which will have 50 subdomains and I found a solution to load separate `.env` file based on a domain name and everything is working fine... now my problem is

> I have to run command `config:cache` to clear the cache so sytem can load relevant `.env` file, otherwise, it keeps loading the older `.env` file. How can i ask system to do cache clear on each load in `bootstrap/app.php` file???

My Code to load `.env` files in `bootstrap/app.php`

```
$domain = '';
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])){
    $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
}

    if ($domain) {
        $dotenv = \Dotenv\Dotenv::create(base_path(), '.env.'.$domain.'.env');
    
        try {
            $dotenv->overload();
    
        } catch (\Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $e) {
            // No custom .env file found for this domain
        }
    }
```

Comment: how about you just stop caching the config

Comment: will that be a good prectice?

Comment: if you are dynamically loading env files then caching isn't doing anything for you since you are constantly dynamically loading an env file

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against doing that because things WILL break.

However, to answer your question, you can use `Artisan::call('config:clear')` inside a middleware that you can call on each request.

But instead of doing that, you could build a middleware that detects the subdomain you're getting the request from and then call the command instead, just to avoid that extra load.

Comment: thanks for answering, can u please explain a bit what things will break?

Comment: this is not working.. it gives 419 page expired error when i try to post anything

Answer (score 0):

I used another way to solve this on my project. It is setting the config dynamically according to the request. The config is only valid for the current request. If the count of the dynamic config is less you can use

```
Config::set('myConfig.hostName', $hostName);
```

Before doing that you must use the package

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
```